# Multi Domain Sharepoint user profiles

Tags: people-search, active-directory-import

We have a sharepoint where we have to use 3 AD domains (eg: domA, domB, domC) to pull users from. Sometimes there are users who would appear in all these domains(domA\User1, domB\User1, domC\User1). How can we configure Employee Directory to avoid these duplicate values. Currently, people search employee directory shows three different entries for the same user: "User1" instead I would like to see only one entry per user. Please suggest.

Comment: Is there some kind of unique identifier shared among the domains, e. g. employee number? If not, you'd have to try to match based on some property of the person, e. g. phone number or name.

Comment: the 'AccountName' is unique.

Comment: Do you have the user profile configuration set to avoid duplication? That setting was designed for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to work with the AD teams that manage those. You would have to identify the duplicate users and move them to specific OU. Then you can configure People Picker to exclude those OUs from the query.